# How to compute the circumference of a geodesic circle on the cylinder?

Tags: differential-geometry

? [image]

[image]

Here, the geodesic circle of radius r centered at p is the set of all points whose geodesic distance from p is equal to r. Let $C(r)$ denote the circumference of this circle. I want to apply this formula in case of the cylinder whose equation is $x^2+y^2=R^2$ with $z$ arbitrary. But, I can't figure out how to compute $C(r)$ for the cylinder. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I think this is the answer: the cylinder is a developeable surface. When you unroll it the geodesic circle becomes an ordinary circle, with no change in circumference. Posting only as a comment since I'm not certain.

Comment: Not clear to me what you are asking.  The geodesics are helices.  And the Gaussian curvature of a cylinder is zero.  It is isometric to a rectangle.  Presumably the area of a geodesic disc would just be $\pi r^2$.

Comment: Ok I will specify more.

Comment: I.e., working backwards from the theorem, since the curvature is zero the area of the geodesic disc must be $\pi r^2$.

Comment: I want to know the method to calculate the circumference....not the result

Comment: Are you willing to use the fact that the cylinder is isometric to a rectangle?  Then it's a one liner.

Comment: It is not intuitively clear that the cylinder is isometric to a rectangle. Cylinders are curved so I cannot easily match them to rectangles,

Comment: cylinders are only curved in one direction.  the Gaussian curvature is the product of the two curvatures, one of which is zero.  Imagine taking the label off a tin can.  flatten it.  If there were a grid on the tin can label, it will not be distorted when you flatten it.

Answer (score 0):

The Gaussian curvature (the product of the two principal curvatures) of a cylinder is zero.  This is because principal curvature in the direction along the long axis is zero and so the product of the two is zero.  A surface with zero Gaussian curvature is **developable:**  [That is, it is a surface that can be flattened onto a plane without distortion (i.e. "stretching" or "compressing").](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface) So, in the plane the answer is $2 \pi r$ for the circumference or $\pi r^2$ for the area.  You can also show that two surfaces with the same Gaussian curvature are locally isometric, which is all, I think, you need.

Comment: The last result is far deeper than anything needed for this! Indeed, you can make a cylinder by turning a rectangle into a cylinder (attach two parallel sides), so draw the picture (small enough, anyhow) on the rectangle.